# How to emulate click on OVERVIEW button in Appium

Tags: android, action, appium

I need to emulate click on overview button on Android(the same combination ctrl + O). My target is -- open list of applications whcih are in background right now.
In this place I haven't found that action:

```
public interface AndroidKeyCode {
    int BACK = 4;
    int BACKSPACE = 67;
    bla bla
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your need:

```
AndroidDriver aDriver = (AndroidDriver) driver;
aDriver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);
aDriver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH);
List<WebElement> appsInBackground = driver.
  findElementsById("com.android.systemui:id/activity_description");
//select the one you need and open by click
```

Answer (score 0):

The keycode for showing the list of all the background apps in Android is **KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH** for which the integer value is **187**

You can use below command to view the switch app window :

```
adb shell input keyevent 187
```

OR

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
```

Comment: @Andrey is this working for you? It is working for me